# SwiftyJson is it possible to iterate through objects but not arrays?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I have object

```
 {"FIELD NAME":{
         "SUBNAME":{
            "FIELD_ONE":"DATA",
            "FIELD_TWO":"DATA",
          }
          "SUBNAME2":{
            "FIELD_THREE":"DATA",
            "FIELD_FOUR":"DATA",
          }
 }
```

I want to get data from SUBNAME and SUBNAME2. Problem is that I dont know name of these fields and how many of them there are.

Is it possible to iterate through them using SwiftJSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting your JSON to an object, you can do this:

`for (subname, dictionary) in json {
    // use subname and the dictionary, which contains the FIELD_* entries
}`

Comment: Thanks for reply! By converting you mean something like var json = JSON(data:data) ?

Comment: is it possible to use than construction not over whole JSON object, but on part of it ? I have huge file and im interested only in a little part of it

Comment: So how do you hold the data to your json file? How would you access the parameters if you _would know_ the fields?

Comment: I know most of file structure, and I know object, that I need to parse, but inside this one there is several objects inside object but not array so I dont understand how to iterate :(

Comment: I figured It out, how to parse, using your advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be great to see your solution, in case anyone else wonders how to do what you wanted to do. You could edit my answer or add a new answer instead.